# Magento 2.2.4 Upgrade issue : Area is already set

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme, magento-upgrade

I have upgraded to version 2.2.4 from 2.2.3 now I'm getting error when try to save theme seting 
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same; no idea what that means.

Comment: Me too, it must be a bug, also I noticed that my product meta titles are gone in simple products and breadcrumbs are gone too also the back button text has changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**This is a re-owned issue of Magento 2.2.4 C.E.**

Magento has been fixed  by Daniel Ruf at 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7019a0a1392095185505ff3ca7b97dd3e9cb4ef2
at [PR #15137](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/15137) and  already merge  at [2.2-develop branch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php)

You need to modify the code of  `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate`  **setForcedArea** method and  Replace that method code using below one.

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if (!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And it will be released on coming any version.Still is not fixed [2.2.5](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968)

Comment: It is not released in 2.2.5. I am getting same error in CE 2.2.5. Can you please help me to override this file ?

Comment: The above fix is not working for me in version 2.2.5. is there any other solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

It's thrown by this function in file `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php` on line 570.

Note I have commented out the error throwing part - which allows me to change the theme with what seems to be no ill effects. You could probably get the same results.

```
/**
 * Store the area associated with a template so that it will be returned by getDesignConfig and getDesignParams
 *
 * @param string $templateId
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
 */
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    #if ($this->area) {
    #    throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
    #}
    $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me overriding vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php?

Comment: Your solution is working great if I make changes in the vendor file, but since the class is an abstract class, I am not able to override it.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora How did you override it ? I have tried to override it using the plugin way, but not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MGento, please try this https://github.com/pfortin-expertime/MageFix-Misc

Comment: @MGento, Can you post a question for this and upvote my answer there?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, deal. Here is the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231851/magento-2-2-5-bug-cannot-update-theme-bug-fix-not-able-to-override-the-abstra

Comment: @MGento, I have answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have overridden this function using a plugin.
Please find my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232745/48571

Answer (score 0):

Don't need plugin. Just apply patch.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

```
mkdir ./patches         
mkdir ./patches/composer
```

./patches/composer/area.patch

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php
index fa9d280..ecd6502 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php
@@ -534,10 +534,10 @@ abstract class AbstractTemplate extends AbstractModel implements TemplateTypesIn
      */
     public function setForcedArea($templateId)
     {
-        if ($this->area) {
-            throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
+        if ($this->area === null) {
+            $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
         }
-        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
+
         return $this;
     }
```

composer.json

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-email": {
                "Design Area code error": "patches/composer/area.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

Run `composer install`