# Magento 2.2.4 & 2.2.5 Bug - Cannot update theme bug fix: Not able to override the abstract class AbstractTemplate

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4, magento-2.2.5

I am having trouble to update the theme in Magento 2.2.5 due to the known issue in `setForcedAre` function of the file `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php`

As per the fixes by Daniel Ruf, updating the `setForcedArea` function will fix the error, but I am having trouble to override the core file `Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php`.

Let me know how to override this core file. I have tried overriding this file using the preference way and also by the plugin way, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Magento 2.x and still not fixed till Magento 2.2.5.

Since the class is an abstract class, we can not override it directly.

Here is a workaround for fixing the issue. Please check the following [link](http://github.com/pfortin-expertime/MageFix-Misc).

I could have written a long answer for this by writing the same code here but why should we write the same code again and again when someone has already fixed it.

Please let me know if it fixed your issue.